# symfony doctrine : retrieve all parents on tree-like structure in one query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, tree, nested

In my project I have severall entities which adopt a tree-like structure.
On some entities I have implemented doctrine nested set behaviour and I have a clear parent-child structure.
On others I defined my self a self-association as I have extra fields in the many to many table.
For instance:

Entity Recipe has $subrecipes
SubRecipe is a new entity with a parameter called weight. SubRecipe $parentRecipe is the parent Recipe. SubRecipe $subRecipe is the child Recipe :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\AppBundle\Entity\FoodAnalytics\Recipe", inversedBy="parentRecipe")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="subrecipeId", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 */
private $subRecipe;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\AppBundle\Entity\FoodAnalytics\Recipe", inversedBy="subrecipes")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parentRecipeId", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, onDelete="cascade")
 */
private $parentRecipe;
```

In order to get a Recipe weight I loop throuh recipes but I then query the database each time.

So far I have :

```
    foreach($this->getSubrecipes() as $subrecipe)
    {
        /**
         * @var $subrecipe RecipeSubrecipe
         */
        $weight += $subrecipe->getSubRecipe()->getWeight();
    }
```

How can I prevent that and retrive the wole tree in one query?
I know I can make a self join on subrecipes but how to repeat this as many times as needed to get the full tree?

```
    $result = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('r')
        ->leftJoin('r.subrecipes', 's')
        ->leftJoin('s.subrecipe', 's1')
        ->leftJoin('s1.subrecipes', 's2')
        ->leftJoin('s2.subrecipe', 's3')
        ->...
    ;
```

Comment: There is the option of defining fetch=EAGER in the mapping but then this is retrived all the time. I think optionnal fetch EAGER might be a solution but I've not implemented this yet...